# Magento simple product attributes - $_item acting weird

Tags: mysql, magento, attributes, magento-1.4, entity-attribute-value

I've been working on a magento site, and was able to pull the simple product attributes with this:

```
$_item->getAttributename()
```

This is on grouped.phtml template since I'm pulling those attributes to the table of a Grouped Product.

It was working fine until some days ago, it just stopped working. It's only showing the Sku and the Price of the simple product. Not displaying the other attributes (like capacity, etc).

I've been messing around with:

```
<?php print('<pre>');print_r($_item->getData());print('</pre>'); ?>
```

And found out that in my local copy it displays the attributes in the array of $_item, but it's not showing them online and that must be why I can't pull them with getAttributename.

My question is, why would the $_item just change like that? And how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a thought that may be off..but have there been any changes to the xml layout files?  All that would need to be changed is the <block type="--------" portion and it would call a different class with different methods.  Are you the only one making edits?

Comment: This is the my thought, have you ever clear the magento cache? Or re-compile the magento code?